# Wizard Inventory: confused with inventory and how to change the values with the code I have

Tags: python, list

I'm doing the def displaytitle(), displayMenu(), show()(I believe), and exiting part right, however, I don't understand what I been doing wrong in def drop_item(), edit_item(), and grab_item(). I also don't get how to change the inventory list, as most of my code doesn't change the list and what I wrote before initiating the code.  I'm really lost and would love some guidance here. Thanks!

Program Instructions and How it should look

[image]

```
def displayTitle():
    print("The Wizard Inventory Program")
def displayMenu():
    print("show - Show all items")
    print("grab - Grab an item")
    print("edit - Edit an item")
    print("drop - Drop an item")
    print("exit - Exit Program")
def show(inventory):
    inventory = ["Wooden Staff", "Wizard Hat", "Cloth Shoes"]
for item in inventory:
    print(item)
def grab_item(inventory):
    item = input("Name: ")
    if inventory < 4:
       print(item + " was added.")
       inventory.append(item)
    else:
       print("Error. Too many")
def edit_item(inventory):
    num = input("Number: ")
    if num == 1:
       print(inventory[0])
       Unum = input("Updated name:")
       print("Item number " + num + " was updated")
       inventory[0] = Unum 
    elif num == 2:
       print(inventory[1])
       Unum = input("Updated name:")
       print("Item number " + num + " was updated")
       inventory[1] = Unum
    elif num == 3:
       print(inventory[2])
       Unum = input("Updated name:")
       print("Item number " + num + " was updated")
       inventory[2] = Unum
    elif num == 4:
       print(inventory[3])
       Unum = input("Updated name:")
       print("Item number " + num + " was updated")
       inventory[3] = Unum
    else:
       print("Invalid Number")
def drop_item(inventory):
    D_item = input("Number: ")
    if D_item == "1":
       inventory.remove("Wooden Staff")
       print("Wooden Staff was dropped")
    elif D_item == "2":
       inventory.remove("Wizard Hat")
       print ("Wizard Hat was dropped")
    elif D_item == "3":
       inventory.remove("Cloth Shoes")
       print("Cloth Shoes was dropped")
    else:
       print("Error!")
def main():
    inventory = ["Wooden Staff", "Wizard Hat", "Cloth Shoes"]
    displayTitle()
    displayMenu()
    while True:
       Com = input("Command: ")
       if Com == "show":
          show(inventory)
       elif Com == "grab":
          grab_item(inventory)
       elif Com == "edit":
          edit_item(inventory)
       elif Com == "drop":
          drop_item(inventory)
       elif Com == "exit":
          break
       else:
          print("Please input a valid Response")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

(1) `inventory` is being reassigned in every call to `show()`. It should just print the contents of the arg `inventory` passed into it.

(2) The if statement in `grab_item()` is trying to compare a list object to an int. Instead it should be `if len(inventory) < 4` to compare with the length of the list.

(3) In `edit_item()`, the input assigned to `num` should be casted to an int so it can be used to index `inventory`. Then you can simplify the code greatly, and catch incorrect numbers with a try/except.

(4) In `drop_item()`, same case as (3) but for `D_item` variable.

Here is the edited code:

```
def displayTitle():
    print("The Wizard Inventory Program")

def displayMenu():
    print("show - Show all items")
    print("grab - Grab an item")
    print("edit - Edit an item")
    print("drop - Drop an item")
    print("exit - Exit Program")

def show(inventory):
    for item in inventory:
        print(item)

def grab_item(inventory):
    item = input("Name: ")
    if len(inventory) < 4:
       print(item + " was added.")
       inventory.append(item)
    else:
       print("Error. Too many")

def edit_item(inventory):
    num = int(input("Number: "))
    try:
        print(inventory[num - 1])
        Unum = input("Updated name:")
        print("Item number " + str(num) + " was updated")
        inventory[num - 1] = Unum
    except IndexError:
       print("Invalid Number")

def drop_item(inventory):
    D_item = int(input("Number: "))
    try:
        print(inventory[D_item - 1] + ' was dropped')
        del inventory[D_item - 1]
    except IndexError:
       print("Error!")

def main():
    inventory = ["Wooden Staff", "Wizard Hat", "Cloth Shoes"]
    displayTitle()
    displayMenu()
    while True:
       Com = input("Command: ")
       if Com == "show":
          show(inventory)
       elif Com == "grab":
          grab_item(inventory)
       elif Com == "edit":
          edit_item(inventory)
       elif Com == "drop":
          drop_item(inventory)
       elif Com == "exit":
          break
       else:
          print("Please input a valid Response")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```